# How to solve $\binom{n}{1}^2+2\binom{n}{2}^2 + 3\binom{n}{3}^2 + 4\binom{n}{4}^2+\cdots + n\binom{n}{n}^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have tried something to solve the series
$$\binom{n}{1}^2+2\binom{n}{2}^2 + 3\binom{n}{3}^2 + 4\binom{n}{4}^2+\cdots + n\binom{n}{n}^2.$$
My approach is :
$$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1}x + \binom{n}{2}x^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}x^n.$$
Differentiating the above equation
$$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2}x + \cdots + n\binom{n}{n}x^{n-1}$$

Also,
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n =\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{x} + \binom{n}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \cdots + \binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n$$
Multiplying above two equation I get,
$$\begin{align*}
&{n(1+x)^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^n}\\
&\quad= \left(
\binom{n}{1}^2 + 2\binom{n}{2}^2 + 3\binom{n}{3}^2 + 4\binom{n}{4}^2 + \cdots + n\binom{n}{n}^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) + \text{other terms}
\end{align*}$$

So I can say that coefficient of $\frac{1}{x}$ in expansion of $n(1+x)^{n-1}(1+\frac{1}{x})^n$ will give me the required answer.

Am I doing it correct,please correct me if I'm wrong ?

If I'm right,please tell me how to calculate the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x}$ ?

Based on the answers,I tried to implement the things in a C++ code.

I tried implementing the code using extended euclidean algorithm so that the problem of truncated division can be eliminated but still not abled to figure out why am I getting wrong answer for n>=3. This is my updated code : http://pastebin.com/imS6rdWs I'll be thankful if anyone can help me to figure out what's wrong with this code.

Thanks.

Solution:

Finally abled to solve the problem.Thanks to all those people who spent their precious time for my problem.Thanks a lot.This is my updated code :

http://pastebin.com/WQ9LRy6F

Comment: There is the [relationship](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27916/squared-binomial-coefficient) $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 x^k=(1-x)^n P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$ where $P_n(z)$ is the Legendre polynomial...

Comment: Looks a bit cumbersome that way. A hint: consider also the sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)\binom{n}{k}^2$. (I expanded this comment in my answer).

Comment: @J.M. :Please explain it in detail.I'm not getting it.

Comment: Yet again we see the promiscuous use of the word "solve".  "Evaluate" is an appropriate word here; "solve" is not.  One solves equations; one solves problems.  One evaluates expressions.

Comment: @code_hacker: the two sums are equal, and are therefore equal to the means of the two ways to write it.

Comment: See also: [$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}^2$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096873)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on the excellent work of @thomas-belulovich & @robjohn,
but addressing your subsequently revealed goal....

You want
$$
T(n)
=S(n)-m\left\lfloor\frac{S(n)}m\right\rfloor
=S(n)\text{ mod }m
\qquad\text{for}\qquad 
S(n)
=\frac{n}{2}{2n\choose n}.
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{S(n)}{S(n-1)}
=\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot\frac{2n(2n-1)}{n^2}
=2\frac{2n-1}{n-1}.
$$
A brute force approach to this might be to calculate
$$
R(k)=2(2k-1)(k-1)^{-1}\pmod m
$$
for each $1<k\le n$ and then multiply modulo $m$ termwise to obtain
$$
T(n)=S(1)\prod_{k=2}^nR(k).
$$
Calculating each $R(k)=(4k-2)x$ requires $O(\log k)$ divisions using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find an $x$ so that
$$
(k-1)x+my=1.
$$

> ***Extended Euclidean Algorithm***:
>   *Given nonzero* $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$,
>   *find* $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$
>   *so that* $ax+by=\text{gcd}(a,b)$.
>   (Adapted from [David Joyner's book](http://wdjoyner.com/teach/book/node65.html).)
>
> 1. Set $\overline{u}=\langle{u_0,u_1,u_2}\rangle$
>         $\leftarrow\langle{a,1,0}\rangle$
>      and $\overline{v}\leftarrow\langle{b,0,1}\rangle$
>      (vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^3$).
>      Set $\overline{v}\leftarrow-\overline{v}$ if $b<0$.
> 2. While $v_0 \ne 0$, repeat:
> 3. $\qquad$ Calculate the quotient
>      $q=\text{quo}(u_0,v_0)=u_0-v_0\left\lfloor\frac{u_0}{v_0}\right\rfloor$.
> 4. $\qquad$ Set
>      $\quad\overline{w}=\overline{u}-q\overline{v},\quad$ then
>      $\quad\overline{u}=\overline{v},\quad$ and then
>      $\quad\overline{v}=\overline{w}.\quad$
> 5. Return
>      $a=u_0$,
>      $x=u_1$, and
>      $y=u_2$.

This is doable in not too many lines of C code,
and it works as long as $m=10^9+7$
has no (prime) factors $p\le n$
(in fact, this $m$ is prime). 
If you needed a more efficient algorithm
and $m$ were a composite product of distinct primes (which it isn't),
you could use the prime factorization of $m$
and a nice fact about binomial coefficients modulo primes [Lukas 1878]
to separately calculate residues
$$
{a\choose b}\equiv{[a/p]\choose[b/p]}{a\mod p\choose b\mod p}\pmod p
$$
modulo each factor $p$, and then recover $T(n)$
using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Here's a few pre-computed values:
$$\matrix{
k& n=10^k &{2n\choose n}\text{ mod }m &T(n)
\\0& 1       &2         &1
\\1& 10      &184756    &923780
\\2& 100     &407336795 &366839610
\\3& 1000    &72475738  &237868748
\\4& 10000   &703593270 &966325381
\\5& 100000  &879467333 &366342189
\\6& 1000000 &192151600 &799327475
}$$

If you want to find an efficient method to solve this problem,
you'll probably want to look at the works of Donald Knuth, [Andrew Granville](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf), and Richard Stanley, who also has compiled outstanding lists of [bijective proof problems](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/bij.pdf) and [characterizations of the Catalan numbers](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf) $C_n=\frac1{n+1}{2n\choose n}$, to which our $S(n)$ are closely related since $S(n)={n+1\choose2}C_n$.

---

One ***might*** be tempted to try to shorten the computation using
Wilson's theorem,
$$
p\text{ prime}
\quad\implies\quad
(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p
$$
Morley's (1895) congruence,
$$
p=2n+1\text{ prime}
\quad\implies\quad
{2n\choose n}\equiv(-1)^n4^{2n}\pmod{p^3}
$$
and/or [Kummer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Divisibility_properties)
using enough "landmark" primes near $n$ and $2n$,
with extended Euclidean algorithm for inverses
and the [CRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (there's the catch!) to get the final result.
For example, here are some prime pairs $q_i=2p_i+1$
near $n=10^6$ and $2n$:
$$
\matrix{
i & p_i-n & q_i-2n \\
1 & -251 & -501 \\
2 & -191 & -381 \\
3 &  151 &  303 \\
4 &  193 &  387 \\
}
$$
From Wilson's theorem for odd primes $q$,
grouping $(q-1)!=(1\cdots\frac{q-1}2)(\frac{q+1}2\cdots q-1)$
and noting that the second term is $(-1)^\frac{q-1}2$
times the first term modulo $q$, we find that
$$
\left(\left(\tfrac{q-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2
\equiv(-1)^{\frac{q+1}2}
\pmod q
$$
so that for prime pairs $q_i=2p_i+1$,
$$
{2p_i\choose p_i}\equiv(-1)^{p_i}=-1\pmod{q_i}.
$$
Thus we can compute (using the extended Euclidean algorithm
for the inverses of $k$ modulo $q_i$)
$$
{2n\choose n}\equiv-\prod_{k=p_i+1}^n\frac{4k-2}{k} \pmod{q_i}
$$
for $i=1,2$ above. ***However***, we cannot use the CRT to get $T(n)$.
We would have to have enough prime pairs to reconstruct $S(n)$,
and then compute its residue at the end.
Since the central binomial coefficient
is approximately $${2n\choose n}\approx\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1-\frac1{nc_n}\right),\qquad c_n\in(8,9)$$
we would need about 96 thousand pairs (p,q),
making this approach infeasible.

Comment: Based on the recursive formula : S(n)/S(n-1) = (4n-2)/(n-1) why shouldn't I pre compute S(n) for all n upto 10^6.Can I do like that ?

Comment: Of course, you can precompute these if it suits your needs. Please not I made some corrections to the ratio $S(n)/S(n-1)$ and hence also (my) $R(n)$.

Comment: Wow I learnt more from this answer. My +1 for this.

Comment: @bgins : I tried to find the multiplicative inverse using extended euclidean algorithm but it's giving me wrong answer for n>=3 In fact the corresponding x(multiplicative inverse) at every step is very large.Can you please tell me where am I doing wrong ? One thing I'm sure of is that my extended_euclid() function is correct as I have tested and implemented it on the description and example of wikipedia.Thanks in advance. Link to the updated code : http://pastebin.com/imS6rdWs

Comment: You have one or two issues left. Your xgcd needs to use signed types since you are subtracting. Also, as a general purpose routine, it's not returning inverses when the gcd is greater than one (which shouldn't be a problem here since $m$ is prime and $0<n<m$). Do you really need this in C++? Why not try [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) or [sage online](http://sagenb.org/)? Type xgcd? or inverse_mod? for example (and `binomial(2*n,n) % m` for a direct, costly, arbitrary precision calculation). Although right now the public server seems to be loaded down.

Comment: @bgins : I think problem is much more than expected.I modified my code and now using only long long data types but still getting absurd results for n>=3.Here is my updated code: http://pastebin.com/FsaZrxe1 One more thing,when I'm calculating x(multiplicative inverse) it sometimes comes out to be negative.why is it coming negative ? Can you please explain the idea of this x in calulcations.On getting x,should I simply multiply it with (4k-2) and then take modulo of that.Is it right ? It might be irritating for you and I'm sorry for that.But I'm really stuck with this code.Please help me.

Comment: I got the c++ code working and it's [quite fast](http://pastebin.com/8G2Tp7nW). You just need to reduce mod $m$ sufficiently often, as @AndreNicolas recommended. Was this homework for math or computer science, or something else?

Comment: @code_hacker: so your background is computer science? or something else? The extended euclidean algorithm is a beautiful algorithm from elementary number theory. An example: gcd$(3,5)=2\cdot3-1\cdot5$. In general, when $a,b>0$, then $x$ & $y$ must have opposite signs. Because of the subtractions, it can produce negative numbers. But, miraculously as it may seem, $x$ and $y$ are never too large in magnitude, so a single addition by $m$ will "correct" a negative sign. It is generally necessary to reduce mod $m$ after every significant operation in order to avoid overflow, as mentioned before.

Comment: @bgins:Thanks finally abled to solve it.Overflow was occuring earlier which need to be reduced using mod m.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 18):

First recall that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{2n}$ implies
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and then note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}^2
&=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{n-k}^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)\binom{n}{k}^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Adding the first and last parts of $(2)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
2\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}^2
&=n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2\\
&=n\binom{2n}{n}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}^2=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{4}
$$

Comment: It looks great but I have one problem with this result.Actually I need to write a code in C to calculate S(result) where n can be as large as 10^6.Although I'm asked to print S % mod as final output where mod=10^9+7 but still calculating S which is derived will definitely overflow.So Can you help me on that part ?

Comment: @code_hacker: This identity might help
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{2n}{n}
&=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{n^2}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{4n-2}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @code_hacker, [this may be useful](http://pweb.nju.edu.cn/zwsun/PRCM-talk.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

This kind of looks like you want to appeal to Vandermonde's convolution, or at least the method you'd use to prove it. It can be applied directly as follows:

Let $S = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n k\binom{n}{k}^2$ be the sum we want to compute. Note that $S = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (n-k) \binom{n}{n-k}^2 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (n-k) \binom{n}{k}^2$. Therefore $2S = n\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 = n \binom{2n}{n}$. Then

$$S = \frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.$$

Comment: It looks great but I have one problem with this result.Actually I need to write a code in C to calculate S(result) where n can be as large as 10^6.Although I'm asked to print S % mod as final output where mod=10^9+7 but still calculating S which is derived will definitely overflow.So Can you help me on that part ?

Answer (score 2):

First we address the overflow issue. Note that $10^9+7$ is relatively prime to all the numbers that come up in a naive calculation of $\binom{2n}{n}$. Indeed $10^9+7$ happens to be prime. So when we are calculating, we can always reduce modulo $10^9+7$ as often as necessary to prevent overflow.

Now to the identity. We have $n$ boys and $n$ girls. We want to choose $n$ people. The number of ways this can be done is $\binom{2n}{n}$. But we can choose $0$ boys and $n$ girls, or $1$ boy and $n-1$ girls, and so on. We can choose $k$ boys and $n-k$ girls in $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$ ways, or equivalently in $\binom{n}{k}^2$ ways. This gives the standard derivation of the identity 
$$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2.$$
Note now that the $\binom{2n}{n}$ choices are all equally likely. The *expected* number of boys is, by symmetry, equal to $\frac{n}{2}.$  But the probability that there are $k$ boys is $\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}$, and therefore the expected number of boys is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}.$$
The term corresponding to $k=0$ is $0$, so can be omitted, and we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{n}{2},$$
which is essentially our identity.

**Remark:** There is a very nice book on bijective proofs called *Proofs that Really Count*. A title that so far doesn't seem to have been used is *Mean Proofs*.

Comment: This is the way to do things, and will definitely run fast enough. (You will have to implement a function that computes multiplicative inverse mod p, but that isn't terrible and runs very quickly.)

Comment: I have implemented the things in a C++ code.This is the link to the code http://pastebin.com/qxQsZyz2 but it's giving me wrong answer when I tried to submit it on online judge.Can any one please tell me where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're dividing by $i$ on line $17$, which is a truncated division. See Thomas's comment and my post about computing inverses modulo $m$ (my post) or mod (your OP notation).

Comment: Nice expected value argument!