# Bijective proof for $\sum\limits_{\substack{n_1+n_2=n\\m_1+m_2=m}}\binom{n_1+m_1}{n_1}^2\binom{n_2+m_2}{n_2}^2=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n+2m+2}{2n+1}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Let $G(x, y)$ be the bivariate generating function for $\binom{i+j}{i}^2$, that is
$$
G(x, y) = \sum\limits_{i,j} \binom{i+j}{i}^2 x^i y^j.
$$
It [can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716262/bivariate-generating-function-for-squared-binomial-coefficients) that
$$
G(x^2, y^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-(x-y)^2)(1-(x+y)^2)}}.
$$
Raising both parts to the power $2$ and regrouping leads to the identity
$$
\sum\limits_{\substack{n_1+n_2=n\\m_1+m_2=m}}\binom{n_1+m_1}{n_1}^2\binom{n_2+m_2}{n_2}^2=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n+2m+2}{2n+1}.
$$
The left-hand side seems to enumerate pairs of paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, m)$ that share a specific point $(n_1, m_1)$. Is there a bijective proof that this number is counted by the right-hand side? Is this a well-known identity?

Comment: You can find a solution [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/286191/136218). I have found the link with [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn_1%2Bn_2%3Dn%2Cm_1%2Bm_2%3Dm%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn_1%2Bm_1%7D%7Bn_1%7D%5E2%5Cbinom%7Bn_2%2Bm_2%7D%7Bn_2%7D%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5Cbinom%7B2n%2B2m%2B2%7D%7B2n%2B1%7D.%24&p=1).